# GraphQL Subscriptions using Express-GraphQL

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, express-graphql, graphql-subscriptions

Can anyone tell me how to implement **GraphQL Subscriptions** using **Express-GraphQL** in Node?

Answer (score 1):

I have also run into the same problem. I wasn't able to find a clear solution to this in the documentation. So i have just switched to graphql-yoga instead. But i did find this thread so [do check it out](https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql/issues/390#issuecomment-371269023)

Answer (score 1):

I've been researching this same issue.

I've read the GitHub issues for `express-graphql` subscriptions and a member of that repo suggested using `graphql-ws` on the closing comment.

Here's a link to my GitHub project [shammelburg/express-graphql-api](https://github.com/shammelburg/express-graphql-api), you can `npm start` load grapiql to test queries and mutation.

To test subscriptions, I've created an Angular project which implements `graphql-ws`'s observables example. [shammelburg/graphql-rxjs-angular](https://github.com/shammelburg/graphql-rxjs-angular)

The Angular project also uses `graphql-request` for queries and mutations.

This is a very lightweight solution and works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

They've added the [doc fragment](https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql/commit/6f888980b87bc45cc27d41e9150df040993d9376) mentioning Subscription Support with an example implementation in Nov 2020.
But unfortunately that never got released, there's an issue [here](https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql/issues/747#issuecomment-813023883) mentioning that.

My workaround for now's been switching over to [Express Playground](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-playground-middleware-express) for the `subscriptions-transport-ws` socket (Playground doesn't support `graphql-ws` yet) and [Apollo Sandbox](https://studio.apollographql.com/sandbox/explorer) for the `graphql-ws`.

Then my subscription creation options are the following.

Where `createScopedPermissionWrapper` is just an `execute` wrapper with `@graphql-authz` and `createGraphqlContext` a factory function validating auth and creating a custom context for my resolvers.

```
import { Server } from 'http'
import { useServer } from 'graphql-ws/lib/use/ws' // subscription with graphql-ws
import { SubscriptionServer } from 'subscriptions-transport-ws' // subscription with subscriptions-transport-ws

export const createSubscriptionsTransportWs = (server: Server) => {
  const wsServer = new SubscriptionServer(
    {
      schema,
      execute: createScopedPermissionWrapper(),
      subscribe,
      onConnect: (args: { authentication?: string }) =>
        createGraphqlContext({
          authentication: args.authentication,
        }),
    },
    { server, path }
  )

  const wsAddress = wsServer.server.address() as AddressInfo
  depClients.logger.success(
    `Graphql subscription socket up on ${wsAddress.address}:${wsAddress.port}${path}`
  )
}

export const createGraphqlWS = (server: Server) => {
  const wsServer = new ws.Server({ server, path })

  useServer(
    {
      schema,
      execute: createScopedPermissionWrapper(),
      subscribe,
      context: (args: { connectionParams: { authentication?: string } }) =>
        createGraphqlContext({
          authentication: args.connectionParams.authentication,
        }),
    },
    wsServer
  )

  const wsAddress = wsServer.address() as AddressInfo
  depClients.logger.success(
    `Graphql subscription socket up on ${wsAddress.address}:${wsAddress.port}${path}`
  )
}
```

Answer (score -3):

See [Authentication and Express Middleware](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/authentication-and-express-middleware/)

```js
var express = require('express');
var graphqlHTTP = require('express-graphql');
var { buildSchema } = require('graphql');

var schema = buildSchema(`
  type Query {
    ip: String
  }
`);

const loggingMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('ip:', req.ip);
  next();
}

var root = {
  ip: function (args, request) {
    return request.ip;
  }
};

var app = express();
app.use(loggingMiddleware);
app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
  schema: schema,
  rootValue: root,
  graphiql: true,
}));
app.listen(4000);
console.log('Running a GraphQL API server at localhost:4000/graphql');
```